# How to open each mininet node in terminator

Tags: mininet, terminator

I tried first opening terminator then executing mininet as sudo, but I couldn't create new sessions within terminator for each mininet node in the topology.

`script -f MININET_NODE_TTY` after `xterm h1` won't work as well because the output of `ip -a`is the same from the original bash session, so I can't properly ping nodes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```sh
sudo mnexec -a [PID] bash
```

for each host PID in the `dump` mininet CLI command.

[image: Example]